# Can I use vaadin code to generate code dynamically using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vaadin-charts

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {
 var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  theme: "theme2",//theme1
  title:{
   text: "Basic Column Chart - CanvasJS"              
  },
  animationEnabled: false,   // change to true
  data: [              
  {
   // Change type to "bar", "area", "spline", "pie",etc.
   type: "column",
   dataPoints: [
    { label: "apple",  y: 10  },
    { label: "orange", y: 15  },
    { label: "banana", y: 25  },
    { label: "mango",  y: 30  },
    { label: "grape",  y: 28  }
   ]
  }
  ]
 });
 chart.render();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can I use vaadin code to generate code dynamically using JavaScript?
I have not tried the append part.

```
enter code here
```

```js
//stackchange.js
        function calc2DArrMulti(dArr) {
            let vLen = dArr.length;
            let eLen = dArr[0].length;
            const result = [];
            const flip = new Array(eLen);
            for (let j = 0; j < eLen; j++) {
                flip[j] = new Array(vLen);
                for (let i = 0; i < vLen; i++) {
                    flip[j][i] = dArr[i][j];
                    if (result[i] == null) result[i] = new Array(eLen);
                }
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < eLen; i++) {
                let min = Math.min.apply(null, flip[i]);
                for (let j = 0; j < vLen; j++) {
                    let v = flip[i][j];
                    result[j][i] = v / min;
                }
            }
            return {
                origin: dArr,
                calc: result
            };
        };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!--Vaadin-charts-->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/stackchange.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/vaadin-charts/vaadin-charts.html">
<!--    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/vaadin-charts/ybtest.html">-->
<!--stacked-->
    <script>
        //----------------임의 데이터 만들기------------------//
        var fab1 = [5, 2200, 100000, 6000000, 5200000, 2200, 100000, 6000000, 5200000,124,124,124,124,124,124];
        var fab2 = [7, 2200, 130000, 4600000, 4200000, 2200, 100000, 6000000, 5200000,124,124,124,124,124,124];
        var fab3 = [7, 2200, 100700, 5600000, 9200000, 2200, 100000, 6000000, 5200000,124,124,124,124,124,124];
        var fab4 = [7, 2200, 100700, 5600000, 9200000, 2200, 100000, 6000000, 5200000,124,124,124,124,124,124];
        var fab5 = [7, 2200, 100700, 5600000, 9200000, 2200, 100000, 6000000, 5200000,124,124,124,124,124,124];
        var test = new Array(5);
        //        var test2 = new Array(4);

        //2차원 배열 선언!!
        for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) { //2
            test[i] = new Array(5);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < fab1.length; i++) {
            test[0][i] = fab1[i];
            test[1][i] = fab2[i];
            test[2][i] = fab3[i];
            test[3][i] = fab4[i];
            test[4][i] = fab4[i];
        }
        //2차원 배열에 1차원 배열 넣기!!
        //----------------임의 데이터 만들기------------------//
        var test2 = calc2DArrMulti(test);
        var test3 = stackchange(test);
    </script>
    <!-- <script>
       $("#test-chart").append("<template><vaadin-column-chartid='dateAxisAndClickEvent'on-point-click='pointClickListener'><x-axis><categories>Fab1,Fab2,Fab3,Fab4,Fab5</categories></x-axis><y-axisallow-decimals='false'min='0'><stack-labelsenabled='false'></stack-labels></y-axis><tooltipformatter='function(){return(test3.origin[this.series.index][this.point.x])}'></tooltip><plot-options><chart-areastacking='percent'></chart-area><columnstacking='percent'><data-labelsenabled='true'color='white'formatter='function(){return(test3.origin[this.series.index][this.point.x])}'></data-labels></column></plot-options><legendlayout='vertical'align='right'vertical-align='top'x='-40'y='80'floating='true'border-width='1'background-color='#FFFFFF'shadow='true'></legend><data-seriesname='1'id='mytib'data='[[mytib]]'></data-series><data-seriesname='2'id='myext'data='[[myext]]'></data-series><data-seriesname='3'id='mybxt'data='[[mybxt]]'></data-series><data-seriesname='4'id='mycxt'data='[[mycxt]]'></data-series><data-seriesname='5'id='mydxt'data='[[mydxt]]'></data-series><data-seriesname='6'id='mydxx'data='[[mydxx]]'></data-series><data-seriesname='7'id='mydxz'data='[[mydxz]]'></data-series><data-seriesname='8'id='mydxy'data='[[mydxy]]'></data-series><data-seriesname='9'id='mydxr'data='[[mydxr]]'></data-series><data-seriesname='10'id='mydxh'data='[[mydxh]]'></data-series><data-seriesname='11'id='mydx1'data='[[mydx1]]'></data-series><data-seriesname='12'id='mydx2'data='[[mydx2]]'></data-series><data-seriesname='13'id='mydx3'data='[[mydx3]]'></data-series><data-seriesname='14'id='mydx4'data='[[mydx4]]'></data-series><data-seriesname='15'id='mydx5'data='[[mydx5]]'></data-series></vaadin-column-chart></template>");
</script>-->
<dom-module id=test-chart> 
         <template>
        <vaadin-column-chart id='dateAxisAndClickEvent'   on-point-click='pointClickListener'>
        <x-axis>
            <categories>Fab1,Fab2,Fab3,Fab4,Fab5</categories>
        </x-axis>
        <y-axis allow-decimals='false' min='0'>
            <stack-labels enabled='false'></stack-labels>
        </y-axis>
       <tooltip formatter= 'function() { return (test3.origin[this.series.index][this.point.x])}'></tooltip>
        <plot-options>
            <chart-area stacking='percent'>
            </chart-area>
            <column stacking='percent'>
            <data-labels enabled='true' color='white' formatter= 'function() { return (test3.origin[this.series.index][this.point.x])}'></data-labels>
            </column>
        </plot-options>
         <legend layout='vertical' align='right' vertical-align='top' x='-40' y='80' floating='true' border-width='1' background-color='#FFFFFF' shadow='true'></legend>

        <data-series name='1'id='mytib' data='[[mytib]]'></data-series>
        <data-series name='2'id='myext' data='[[myext]]'></data-series>
        <data-series name='3'id='mybxt' data='[[mybxt]]'></data-series>
        <data-series name='4'id='mycxt' data='[[mycxt]]'></data-series>
        <data-series name='5'id='mydxt' data='[[mydxt]]'></data-series>
        <data-series name='6'id='mydxx' data='[[mydxx]]'></data-series>
        <data-series name='7'id='mydxz' data='[[mydxz]]'></data-series>
        <data-series name='8'id='mydxy' data='[[mydxy]]'></data-series>
        <data-series name='9'id='mydxr' data='[[mydxr]]'></data-series>
        <data-series name='10' id='mydxh' data='[[mydxh]]'></data-series>
        <data-series name='11' id='mydx1' data='[[mydx1]]'></data-series>
        <data-series name='12' id='mydx2' data='[[mydx2]]'></data-series>
        <data-series name='13' id='mydx3' data='[[mydx3]]'></data-series>
        <data-series name='14' id='mydx4' data='[[mydx4]]'></data-series>
        <data-series name='15' id='mydx5' data='[[mydx5]]' ></data-series>
    </vaadin-column-chart>
        </template>       
              </dom-module> 
        <script>
            Polymer({
                is: 'test-chart',
                properties: {
                    mytib: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: test3.calc[0]
                    },
                    myext: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: test3.calc[1]
                    },
                    mybxt: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: test3.calc[2]
                    },
                    mycxt: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: test3.calc[3]
                    },
                    mydxt: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: test3.calc[4]
                    },
                    mydxx: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: test3.calc[5]
                    },
                    mydxz: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: test3.calc[6]
                    },
                    mydxy: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: test3.calc[7]
                    },
                    mydxr: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: test3.calc[8]
                    },
                     mydxh: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: test3.calc[9]
                    },
                     mydx1: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: test3.calc[10]
                    },
                     mydx2: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: test3.calc[11]
                    },
                     mydx3: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: test3.calc[12]
                    },
                     mydx4: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: test3.calc[13]
                    },
                     mydx5: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: test3.calc[14]
                    },
                },
            pointClickListener: function(a) {
                var b = a.detail.originalEvent,
                    c = a.detail.point,
                    d = b.chartX,
                    f = b.chartY;
                this.showLabel(c.series.name+':' + test3.origin[c.series.index][c.x], d, f)
            },
            showLabel: function(a, b, c) {
                var d = this.$.dateAxisAndClickEvent.chart.renderer.label(a, b, c).attr({
                    fill: 'red',
//                    Highcharts.getOptions().colors[5],
                    padding: 5,
                    r: 5,
                    zIndex: 8
                }).css({
                    color: '#FFFFFF'
                }).add();
                this.async(function() {
                    d.fadeOut()
                }, 1e3)
            }
            });
        </script>
    <test-chart></test-chart>
</body>

</html>
```

I have not tried the append part.

I want to code the vaadin chart like a canvas.

Is it possible?

What should I do if possible?

Comment: you've asked the same question three times in this one post - why have you done that?

Comment: I want to code the vaadin chart like a canvas.

Is it possible?

What should I do if possible?